# How to iterate a Map<string,string> Array using ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript, dictionary, ngfor

I have a property like this:

```
const carac = new Map<string,string>();//Declare my property
carac.set("Color", "Blue"); // Set key value
carac.set("age", "99"); // set another key value
```

I have also an array like this:

```
caracteristicas:Map<string, string>[];
```

then i push my propery inside my array like this:

```
caracteristicas.push(carac);
```

in my html i want to iterate my array and show key and values, I have done this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let caracteristica of caracteristicas | keyvalue ; let i = index">
                <td>
                    {{caracteristica.key}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{caracteristica.value}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button (click)="quitarCaracteristica(i)">
                        <i class="fas fa-minus"></i>
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

I am using the key value pipe but when I run my app it does not work, it does not show my keys and my values, just show something like that:    `[object Map]`. Any ideas how to show my key and values, I'm using Angular 9, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the map and then putting it inside an array, however in your  ngFor loop, you are directly trying to access that map, but first you need to iterate the array, and then further extract the map object.

Try below code, you can manipulate it according to your requirements,

```
<tr *ngFor="let caracteristica of caracteristicas;let i = index">
<ng-container *ngFor="let mapItem of caracteristica | keyvalue ">
                <td>
                    {{mapItem .key}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{mapItem .value}}
                </td>
         </ng-container>
                <td>
                    <button (click)="quitarCaracteristica(i)">
                        <i class="fas fa-minus"></i>
                    </button>
                </td>
            
</tr>
```

Comment: Please explain _what_ and _why_ you changed it, others will benefit from your answer as well.

Comment: Okay, I'm going to try it in a better way, excuse for my english. You cannot directly use the keyvalue pipe in your ngFor, so nobalG did two ngFor, in the first one he is getting the map, and then is looping over its keys and its values.

Comment: @JackyShows I am sorry, but we can use keyvalue directly on map, I want to clarify that I used two loops only because the map is pushed into an array(see the question), so first loop  is extracting the map out of that array, and then in the second loop we have that extracted map object, which s being iterated using keyvalue pipe